# Firebase Insert data with 2 key attributes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to the Firebase concept but what I am trying to do is add a new Firebase element into my "Groups" category where the tree structure is as such:

```
Groups:
---- GroupID (provided by firebase)
    ---- GroupPW (provided by user that create new group)
        ---- GroupName (provided by user that create new group)
        ---- etc....
```

I have the following in the ViewController, under the CreateGroup IBAction button:

```
    let group = Group(groupName: self.name.text!, groupPW: self.password.text!)

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let key = ref.child("Groups").childByAutoId().key


    taskFirebasePath.setValue(group.toDictionary())
```

I am not really sure what to do now?

Comment: What happens when the password of the group needs to change? Using a password as a key is a HUGE red flag. You can't change/rename keys in firebase. Unless you have a very good reason, passwords should be a property of your group and you should use a good password specific encryption system (like BCrypt). Even if you don't think the passwords need to be "secure", users will use (share) passwords that ARE high security somewhere else.

Comment: @Mike can you share how I can implement the password encryption system? I am a little confused about that.

Comment: Check out this article: http://codetheory.in/using-the-node-js-bcrypt-module-to-hash-and-safely-store-passwords/

Comment: @Mike how would i use BCrypt with swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `taskFirebasePath` is. But if you wanna insert data to `group`, I think should change it to.

```
let group = Group(groupName: self.name.text!, groupPW: self.password.text!)

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let childRef= ref.child("Groups").childByAutoId().child(self.password.text!)

childRef.setValue(group.toDictionary())
```

Comment: This only deals with one level, not two levels?

Comment: Your mean `groupPW` contains `groupName`?

Comment: See the initial question. Its GroupID then Password and then the rest of the Group Info

Comment: func toDictionary() -> Any {
        return [
            "GroupName": self.groupName,
        ]
    }